# Replace yaxis values with text

Tags: matlab

I have a list of labels:

```
lnames = {'nameA','nameB','nameC'}
```

and a vector with indices:

```
Y = [1; 1; 2; 3; 2];
```

`index(1)` refers to `nameA`, `index(2)` to `nameB` etc.

I want to show when a certain name is selected:

```
plot(Y, 'd')
```

This gives me a plot (on bigger scale as follows):

[image]

However, I want to replace the numerical values on the yaxis with the labels. Thus `1` becomes `nameA`, `2` becomes `nameB`, etc. It would look as follows:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Check the properties `Ytick` and `YtickLabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `YTick` and `YTickLabel` for the axis of your plot as follows.

```
h = plot(Y, 'd');
h.Parent.YTick = 1:numel(lnames);
h.Parent.YTickLabel = lnames;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Y = [1; 1; 2; 3; 2];
yticks([1 2 3])
yticklabels({'nameA', 'nameB', 'nameC'})
plot(Y, 'd');
```